# How to obtain values of all Apache's mod_rewrite environment variables, without PHP?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache instance *but without PHP* (almost all the SO answers I found for this are PHP-specific). In fact it's mostly serving static content.

I'm working on some `mod_rewrite` redirections and I'd like to know the exact values of all environment variables.

Those pages list Apache's available env variables and example values

- http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/env_var.htm
- https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/

however *I'd like to see the exact values coming from my requests, to facilitate working on my rewrite rules*.

**What would be the easiest way to get all the Apache environment values?** (without installing PHP on it).

As a *poor man's debugging*, I know I can get values one by one by defining some example rewrites like this

```
 RewriteRule ^/test.htm http://localhost/test2.htm?SERVER_NAME=%{SERVER_NAME}  [R,L,NC]
```

and then hitting `http://localhost/test.htm` and observing the redirect, but this is not a really good solution.

Is there a better way to learn about all the environment, not specific to any particular language like PHP?

Comment: There are many languages that can interact with Apache and read environment variables; it isn't mandatory to use PHP. But you need to be able to *execute* something since Apache itself will not just happily report all the environment to the outside world. (Well, [perhaps it can](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html), I cannot check right now because it refuses to work in my computer.)

Comment: mod_info looks promising, I'll check that!

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the values of all Apache environment variables with Perl. The standard Apache distribution still bundles the good old `printenv.pl` CGI script. Here's what mine (Apache/2.4 on Windows) looks like:

```
#!D:/programs/perl/bin/perl.exe
#

# To permit this cgi, replace # on the first line above with the
# appropriate #!/path/to/perl shebang, and on Unix / Linux also
# set this script executable with chmod 755.
#
# ***** !!! WARNING !!! *****
# This script echoes the server environment variables and therefore
# leaks information - so NEVER use it in a live server environment!
# It is provided only for testing purpose.
# Also note that it is subject to cross site scripting attacks on
# MS IE and any other browser which fails to honor RFC2616. 

##
##  printenv -- demo CGI program which just prints its environment
##
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
foreach my $var (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
    my $val = $ENV{$var};
    $val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;
    $val =~ s|"|\\"|g;
    print "${var}=\"${val}\"\n";
}
```

Of course:

- You need Perl installed
- Apache administrator will typically not enable the default /cgi-bin directory

Other that using a program, you're out of luck. I'm not aware of any builtin Apache module that reports ENV variables (not even `mod_info`).